# preg_split unexpected behavior

Tags: php, preg-split

I use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) as the following:

```
<?php
$num = 99.14;
$pat = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]";
$segments = preg_split($pat, $num);
print_r($segments);
```

I expected that $segments will be an array like `array(99,14)` However, it returns `array(99.14)` I don't know why preg_split do that while the pattern by which it should split the string is any special character i.e non alphanumeric.

Check this demo: http://codepad.org/MUusnwis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add delimiters to your regex like this:

```
<?php

    $num = 99.14;
    $pat = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/";
          //^------------^Delmimiter here
    $segments = preg_split($pat, $num);
    print_r($segments);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 99 [1] => 14 )
```

**EDIT:**

The question why OP got the entire string back in the array is simple! If you read the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

And take a quick quote from there under notes:

> Tip
>   If matching fails, an array with a single element containing the input string will be returned.

Comment: I posted the same but deleted it after seeing your answer. But why does it return the whole string without the `/` though? I'm a bit puzzled on that one.

Comment: I think it is due to the regular expressions engine specifications of PHP

Comment: Ah, because its split not match. Duh, I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to split along the decimal, you could also use:

```
$array = explode('.', $num);
```

Comment: I want `preg_split` to cover any variations for local settings. it may be 99,14 too!

Comment: You can get that from PHP - see http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php. You'd have to get the locale, of course, so your original solution is probably more easily robust.

Comment: you have many values for some similar inputs. i.e 1,520 what do you regard `,` a thousands_sep or decimal_point ?

Comment: That will be a problem with preg_split as well. Seems you can't avoid using localeconv() to determine the delimiter if you want your code to be robust.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx tool](https://t-regx.com) and you won't have such problems :)

Delimiters are not required

```
<?php
$num = 99.14;
$segments = pattern("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")->split($num);

print_r($segments);
```